# Asynchronous HTTP post with JSON parsing the result with Android 4?

Tags: android, json, http, http-post

I'm quite new to Android. I've been looking for a good example on how to perform a HTTP post request over the web, but I'm hesitating on which to use since I'm only developing for Android 4. I want something asynchronous, fast and simple. An example with JSON result parsing would be much appreciated. Any ideas? Should I use Apache HTTP Client or HttpURLConnection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me [RestTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/rest-template.html) is one of the easiest ways to consume REST services on Android.

Example for JSON:

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

    //setting timeout
    requestFactory.getHttpClient().getParams().setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT,
            HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    requestFactory.getHttpClient().getParams().setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT,
            HTTP_TIMEOUT);

    template.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

    //setting converter for JSON
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = template.getMessageConverters();
    converters.add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
    template.setMessageConverters(converters);


    ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> response = template.postForEntity(URL, requestObject, ResponseObject.class);

    ResponseObject result = response.getBody();
```

To make this works You need RestTemplate and jackson(I think it should be jackson-all) jars in your project. You can find links to those jars in RestTemplate documentation(link above).

To make this asynchronous use  AsyncTask from Android SDK.